# How would I use the same browser instance for different test cases in Watir?

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I want to use the same browser for both test cases.  I don't want to open a new browser for each and every case.

```
require File.expand_path("..",Dir.pwd)+"/TestHelper"

class Validations < Test::Unit::TestCase

    def initializer
      browser = self.getBrowser
      if browser.nil?
        p "browser nil"
        helper = TestHelper.new
        email = helper.getCurrentEmailAddress
        url = UtilConstants::HOME_PAGE+UtilConstants::SIGN_UP
        browser = helper.getExistingBrowser
        if browser.nil?
          browser = helper.getBrowser
          browser.goto url
        end
      end
      return browser
    end

    def test_email_field_validation
      #code 
    end

    def test_password_field_validation
     #code
    end
end
```

Comment: I'd suggest taking a look at the Test::Unit example on http://watir.com/frameworks/.  It shows how to create a memoized browser object in the built-in `setup` method (and there's a similar example for rspec).

Answer (score 0):

You should use instance variable i.e. `@browser`. Create it once in initializer and use inside methods like this:

```
def test_email
    email_elem = @browser.element(:id => "email")
    assertTrue(email_elem.exists?)
    ...
end
```